# How to create a file with timestamp in `terraform`?

Tags: terraform

I use below configuration to generate a filename with `timestamp` which will be used in many different places.

```
variable "s3-key" {
  default = "deploy-${timestamp()}.zip"
}
```

but got `Error: Function calls not allowed` error. How can I use `timestamp` for a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable defaults in particular are constant values, but local values allow for arbitrary expressions derived from variables:

```
variable "override_s3_key" {
  default = ""
}

locals {
  s3_key = var.override_s3_key != "" ? var.override_s3_key : "deploy-${timestamp()}.zip"
}
```

You can then use `local.s3_key` elsewhere in the configuration to access this derived value.

---

With that said, Terraform is intended for creating long-running infrastructure objects and so including timestamps is often (but not always!) indicative of a design problem. In this particular case, it looks like using Terraform to create application artifacts for deployment, which is something Terraform *can* do but Terraform is often not the best tool for this sort of job.

Instead, consider splitting your build and deploy into two separate steps, where the build step is implemented using any separate tool of your choice -- possibly even just a shell script -- and produces a versioned (or timestamped) artifact in S3. Then you can parameterize your Terraform configuration with that version or timestamp to implement the "deploy" step:

```
variable "artifact_version" {}

locals {
  artifact_s3_key = "deploy-${var.artifact_version}.zip"
}
```

An advantage of this separation is that by separating the versioned artifacts from the long-lived Terraform objects you will by default retain the historical artifacts, and so if you deploy and find a problem you can choose to switch back to a known-good existing artifact by just re-running the deploy step (Terraform) with an older artifact version. If you instead manage the artifacts directly with Terraform, Terraform will delete your old artifact before creating a new one, because that's Terraform's intended usage model.

There's more detail on this model in the HashiCorp guide [Serverless Applications with AWS Lambda and API Gateway](https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/aws/lambda-api-gateway). You didn't say that the `.zip` file here is destined for Lambda, but a similar principle applies for any versioned artifact. This is analogous to the workflow for other deployment models, such as building a separate Docker image or AMI for each release; in each case, Terraform is better employed for the process of selecting an existing artifact built by some other tool rather than for creating those artifacts itself.

Comment: I think there's a use case where I want my RDS instance to have a unique final snapshot identifier that shows the timestamp. Additionally, existing `timestamp()` call isn't ideal since it is evaluated when I apply the terraform, but I want a timestamp that is evaluated lazily. Is there such a feature? Or any best practice for naming final snapshots? Ideally something that will be unique when evaluated, but does not dirty my terraform-plan

Comment: For that specific case, I'd suggest starting a feature request discussion in the AWS provider repository about it, because it seems like something that would be more straightforward to build as a feature of `aws_db_instance` specifically, rather than shifting Terraform's overall model to producing "versioned" or "timestamped" artifacts.